# Continuity of $r\left(t\right)=\cos^2\left(2t\right)\hat{i}+\sin\left(3t\right)\hat{j}$ along $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$

Tags: continuity

I had a bonus on a quiz that gave me the vector function
\begin{align}
r\left(t\right)=\cos^2\left(2t\right)\hat{i}+\sin\left(3t\right)\hat{j},\tag{1}
\end{align}
and asked me if it was continuous along $\left[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. Because differentiability implies continuity (e.g. [this proof](http://www-math.mit.edu/~djk/18_01/chapter02/proof04.html)) my thoughts were that it was continuous over the entire interval except at the endpoints, where I don't believe it is differentiable. Here is a graph of the function from Mathematica:

[image]

It appears to oscillate back and forth over this graph no matter what the bounds.

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 0):

This graph is differentiable with respect to $t$. Don't mix up graphs of vector valued functions with functions like $y=f(x)$!

Comment: Okay that makes sense...I do see that both components are differentiable everywhere, I was just wondering about the endpoints that appear. Interesting. Thanks!